# What this function (probably callback) is doing in this code?

Tags: javascript, callback, higher-order-functions

So after 3 days I've started to understand what callback function actually is and just come across this code:

```
const timeFuncRuntime = funcParameter => {

    let t1 = 120;
    
    funcParameter();
    
    let t2 = 200;
    
    return t2 - t1;
    
}
    
const addOneToOne = () => 1 + 1;
    
timeFuncRuntime(addOneToOne);
    
console.log(timeFuncRuntime(addOneToOne))
```

With just my 3 months experience in JS (which I'm aware is nothing), I can tell that in this line of code "timeFuncRuntime(addOneToOne);" another function is being passed as an argument which is 'addOneToOne' however, I don't understand what it's actually doing here? What's the point of having it there?

In the last line when the main function is called with another function being passed as an argument, that function (probably that's what a callback function is called) is returning 1+1 = 2 however, it's just returning and I don't think there's any need for that, or is there?

In the first arrow function, two local variables are declared with different values with a callback function (I think it's a callback) so what is that callback function doing there?

Comment: looks to me like timeFuncRuntime is supposed to return the time it took to run another function (addOneToOne for example) , but whomever wrote forgot to replace t1 and t2 with actual time

Comment: @MaherFattouh - What about any other numeric value than time?

Answer (score 0):

This code all appears to be useless.

- The function passed is a pure function, but its result is never used, so it isn't doing anything meaningful.
- The wrapper `timeFuncRuntime` will always return `80`, which also isn't very useful.

That means this code is essentially equivalent to:

```
console.log(80)
```

Just with extra processing.

---

This code is likely attempting to show use of [Higher Order Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), but isn't doing so very effectively. The `t2 - t1` looks like it's attempting to show how you'd write a benchmarking function, but they hardcoded in numbers which defeats the purpose.

Study functions like `map` and `reduce` to get better examples of why you'd want to pass functions around.

---

What they were likely going for is something like this:

```
const benchmark = (f) => {
    let t1 = Date.now();
    f();
    let t2 = Date.now();
    return t2 - t1;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
let t = benchmark(() => {
    // Something expensive
    for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        let d = new Date()
    }
});

// Prints how long it took the function to execute.
// A number around 50 for me.
console.log(t);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @imheretolearn See the bottom of my answer. I improved it.

Comment: Yes, that was the original code and I changed from Date.now() to the simple values to make the question look simple. But both are returning some numeric values and having that callback function in b/t two Ts(t1 and t2) still makes no sense to me.

Comment: @imheretolearn It's timing how long `f` takes to execute. `t1` is the current time before the function is run, `t2` is the current time after the function is run. The difference between the times is how long the function took to run.